# Validation and Learning Curves with Pipeline or Model Only?

Tags: cross-validation, scikit-learn, model-evaluation

I have a pretty complex Sklearn pipeline including Standardization, PCA, and more.

I created a couple of models and would like to evaluate them with learning and validation curves.

I find myself wondering whether if I should use the entire pipeline object or just the final model for drawing the curves. I presume the former.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct answer is the former. One should always cross validate with the entire pipeline as even steps such as feature selection have a dependency on the dataset split chosen.